# Removing pinning from the hip joint

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

(Forwarded from [DRC Forum](http://forum.theroboticschallenge.org/index.php?topic=25.0))

Hi,
I understand that balancing is still not implemented, but if I'd wish to implement it, how could I remove the pinning so that the robot would actually fall to the ground. I remember there should be some static tag in the urdf file of the robot (`/usr/share/drcsim-1.0/ros/drc_robot_utils` ?) but was not able to locate it.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/141/removing-pinning-from-the-hip-joint/) by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1414 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was able to unpin the hip following the settings for DRCRobotPlugin.cc which I found on bitbucket here:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/24/pull-request-21-with-minor-fix-branched/diff#chg-plugins/ros/DRCRobotPlugin.cc

To unpin, run the DRC simulator per the tutorial, and in a separate console publish a topic to /mode:

rostopic pub /mode std_msgs/String "unpinned"

Looks like you've got 4 options for the time being.

---

Originally posted by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) with karma: 61 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0